doNothing when on abstract class method but should work when called from concreate class instance
I have following structure:
class Sample {
 private Map<String A> serviceMap;

 @Autowired
 private List<A> services;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
  this.serviceMap = this.services.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getName, s -> s)); 
 }

 public void doSomething() {
   // Some logic, and gets the serviceName
   this.serviceMap.get(serviceName).process(...);
 }
}

Now how to test this doSomething method of Sample class. I don't want to call the process method of Abstract class A.
I tried to MockBean the services but the problem is how to use doNothing when for this line this.serviceMap.get(serviceName).process(...);.

You can add a getter function for serviceMap. The getter will be package-private for testing purposes.
class Sample {
 private Map<String A> serviceMap;

 @Autowired
 private List<A> services;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init {
  this.serviceMap = this.services.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getName, s -> s)); 
 }

 public void doSomething {
   // Some logic, and gets the serviceName
   getServiceMap().get(serviceName).process(...);
 }

 Map<String A> getServiceMap(){
   return this.serviceMap;
 }
}

Then in your test -
//Given
var sampleSpy = spy(Sample.class);
var serviceMapMock = mock(Map.class);
var serviceAMock = mock(A.class);
when(sampleSpy.getServiceMap()).thenReturn(serviceMapMock);
when(serviceMapMock.get(any())).thenReturn(serviceAMock);
doNothing().when(serviceAMock).process();

//When
sample.doSomething();

//Then
//assertions


Can't extract map out of Sample class.

Getting exception org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:, thenReturn() may be missing on line doNothing().when(serviceMapMock.get(any()));. As the get method is not void hence it is expecting to return something.

@RohitRaj exact implementation added

When you use this,(which refers to the parent class), the method is an instance method and not a static method.
Thus, doSomething can not be called without calling the parent class first to instantiate the class, and this meaning that you will always call the process method of the Abstract Class A in the serviceMap.
If you want to be able to use the doSomething method without instantiating the parent class Sample and not using the Class variable serviceMap, is to allow a mock_service_map attribute to be passed into the doSomething method and also mark that method as a static method that does not use this in the method.
class Sample {
 private Map<String A> serviceMap;

 @Autowired
 private List<A> services;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init {
  this.serviceMap = this.services.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getName, s -> s)); 
 }

 // variable service_map being a Mock serviceMap passed in by the test
 public static void doSomething() {
   // Some logic, and gets the serviceName
   this.serviceMap.get(service_name).process(...);
 }
}

And also thinking about what you want to test and why and then how you'd be able to achieve that.
Having a MockServcie created with a process method that does noting will probably solve the issue you are having.
Hence passing in a MockService into the serviceMap that has a process method that just does nothing will be the correct way in testing the logic of the doSmoehting method and still not doing anyhting on the process method pf the service in the serviceMap.
// Think of this as a base class where the process method has not been implemented?
ServiceName {
  init {
    ...
  }
  
  ...
  
  public void process {
    return;
  }
  
}

serviceMap[] = new ServiceName(...);

sample = new Sample(serviceMap)
some_response = sample.doSemoghting();

//Asserts here from some_response

I hope this helps.

Looks like you mis understand my question. I didn't say anything about making doSomething static method. I want to write unit test case for this method and I don't want to run this line this.serviceMap.get(serviceName).process(...);. I only want to test logic inside doSomething method.

I think it boils down to writing the code in such a way that you have control over the services and variables you instantiate your class(s) with.

A little refactoring can make the class easily testable - use abstraction over the logic to resolve the service name and test the behaviour of Sample.
public class Sample {

  private final Map<String, A> serviceMap;
  private final Supplier<String> serviceResolver;

  public Sample(Map<String, A> serviceMap, Supplier<String> serviceResolver) {
    this.serviceMap = serviceMap;
    this.serviceResolver = serviceResolver;
  }

  public Sample(List<A> services, Supplier<String> serviceResolver) {
    this(services.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getName, s -> s)), serviceResolver);
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    String serviceName = serviceResolver.get();
    this.serviceMap.get(serviceName).process();
  }
}

Verify that:

The service resolver is invoked
Map.get is invoked with the resolved name
The process of the service is invoked

public class SampleTests {

  @Test
  public void testBehaviour() {
    //setup
    A mockService = mock();
    doNothing().when(mockService).process();

    Map<String, A> serviceMap = mock();
    String registeredServiceName = "a";
    when(serviceMap.get(registeredServiceName)).thenReturn(mockService);

    Supplier<String> serviceResolver = mock();
    when(serviceResolver.get()).thenReturn(registeredServiceName);

    //action
    Sample sample = new Sample(serviceMap, serviceResolver);
    sample.doSomething();

    //verifications
    verify(serviceResolver).get();
    verify(serviceMap).get(eq(registeredServiceName));
    verify(mockService).process();
  }
}

If you need to test the logic for resolving the service, then write a unit test for serviceResolver.

I don't think a supplier will suit this case as what will be it's implementation? Those who are injecting Sample will not know how to get/form the correct service name. It is totally Sample responsibility to form service name and get the service from the map if available.

@RohitRaj Supplier is an example, only you know the correct abstraction, because you don't show the logic to resolve the service name (but this logic is irrelevant to the question anyway). Those who are injecting Sample will not know how to get/form the correct service name. - they don't need to know, just inject the resolver the same way you inject services (declare bean/s). It's responsibility of serviceResolver to do it (supplier, function, custom, w/e abstraction matches). Samples responsibility is to call serviceResolver, get the service from the map and call process.

Thanks for the advice but this logic will not be applied in our case as the logic to find the service name is the sole responsibility of the Sample class and if we add a supplier to do that thing then the purpose of Sample is nothing and only becomes caller.
Also, the supplier can't be used here as the supplier will not have the necessary data to form a service name. A function can be used but again can't because of the same reason above.
